# Debugging error in C: Process stopped wtih error code 139

Tags: c, linux, virtual-machine

one of my colleague is running Ubuntu on a VM.
On this machine, CLion is installed.
The projects I've copied on his system, can be built.
But running an executable failes.
We got the error code 139.
(Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV))

So we started with steb-by-step debugging and fint out,
it is possible to create pointers and give them an adress,
but it isn't allowed to allocate memory (using malloc/calloc/...).

Due to we use normal system libraries, which are using e.g. malloc, in our project,
it's it's obviously a bigger problem for us.

Does someone have this error before and knows how we can solve our problem?
I guess, it's a problem with our VM environment, so somehow we have to allow memory allocation.
Am I right?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: Build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building and linking), then just `run` inside a debugger. When the crash (segmentation fault) happens the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. If it's not in your code, then step `up` until you're at your code, and examine the values of all involved variables. The problem is most likely in your code, not in any library.

Comment: You should check compiler and linking options, also versions of gcc and glibc libraries. There can be big differences in the tools between different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` report?  Is SELinux in use in the VM?